# $_GET values are not set during AJAX query

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Basically what I want to happen is for the calendar to go change months upon clicking one of the arrows. I feel like there is a simple error somewhere and that I am just overlooking it. Just let me know if I need to explain something.

calendar.php:

```
<?php
    function calendar($selectedDate = "now") {
            $selectedDate = strtotime($selectedDate);
            $theFirst = strtotime(date('m/01/Y', $selectedDate));
            $weekDayOfTheFirst = (int) date('w', $theFirst);
            $lastDayOfTheMonth = (int) date('j', strtotime('-1 day', strtotime('+1 month', $theFirst)));
            $numberOfWeeks = ceil(($weekDayOfTheFirst + $lastDayOfTheMonth) / 7);
            $selectedMonth = (int) date('m', $selectedDate);

            echo "<table id=\"calendar\"><tr><td onclick=\"updateCalendar('";
            echo date("F", strtotime('-1 month', $selectedDate)) . "', '" . date("Y", strtotime('-1 month', $selectedDate));
            echo "')\"><a href=\"#\">&lt;</a></td><th colspan=\"5\">" . date("F 'y", $selectedDate) . "</th><td onclick=\"updateCalendar('";
            echo date("F", strtotime('+1 month', $selectedDate)) . "', '" . date("Y", strtotime('+1 month', $selectedDate));
            echo "><a href=\"#\">&gt;</a></td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><th>S</th><th>M</th><th>T</th><th>W</th><th>R</th><th>F</th><th>S</th></tr>";
            for ($week = 0; $week < $numberOfWeeks; $week++) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    for ($dayOfTheWeek = 0; $dayOfTheWeek <= 6; $dayOfTheWeek++) {
                            $date = strtotime($dayOfTheWeek + $week * 7 - $weekDayOfTheFirst . 'days', $theFirst);
                            $dayOfTheMonth = (int) date('j', $date);
                            echo "<td" . (date('m/Y', $date) == date('m/Y', $selectedDate) ? "" : " class=\"outOfMonth\"");
                            echo ($date == $selectedDate ? " id=\"today\"" : "") . "><a href=\"#\">" . $dayOfTheMonth . "</a></td>";
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>\n";
    }

    echo "<div>" . $_GET["month"] . "</div><div>" . $_GET["year"] . "</div>";
    if (isset($_GET["month"]) && isset($_GET["year"])) {
            echo "<div>GET</div>";
            calendar($_GET["month"] . ' ' . $_GET["year"]);
    } else {
            echo "<div>not GET</div>";
            calendar();
    }
?>
```

calendar.js:

```
function updateCalendar(month, year) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {    // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("sideBar").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/home2/crompton/scripts/calendar.php?month=" + month + "&year=" + year, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Telling us what is currently happening would be a good start.

Comment: It's in the question. Anyway, `isset($_GET["month"]) && isset($_GET["year"])` returns false. Neither are set.

Comment: @Tyler Specifically how you knew they weren't being set was not at all described in the question.

Comment: @Chacha102, Does it matter? I know they're not set. That should be enough information. Besides, my method is in the code. Do I have to keep reposting my code in the comments?

Comment: @Tyler Judging from your comments, you really don't have a good idea about how PHP and AJAX work. You should read up on them. And while you're at it, read up on how to be nice to people who are trying to help you.

Comment: @Sorry, but honestly, if you want to help me, read the code… I read up on PHP and AJAX. That wasn't enough so that is why I am here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making a GET request to an OS path seems weird to me. How about just making a request to http://localhost/calendar.php?month=4&year=2011 (or whatever you are running your server as).

This would make most sense because the web server is the one that sets the $_GET variables, and that webserver is usually listening to port 80. When you make this call, I'm fairly sure no webserver is listening.

Comment: The idea is to keep the a user from manually navigating to the PHP script.

Comment: However this is not the right solution. You cannot pass $_GET parameters to a file.

Comment: http://w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp The url parameter of the open() method, is an address to a file on a server.

Comment: @Tyler The reason that the tutorial works is that it is running on a **web server** and a **web server** is processing the variables and passing them to PHP. If you don't go through a webserver, you won't get those variables.

Comment: @TylerCrompton: You cannot prevent people from manually accessing URLs. And you cannot access arbitrary paths on the filesystem of servers. If you connect via HTTP the request is handled by the web server and you can only access the files that it provides.

Comment: @Felix, If it's out of the public_html folder…

Comment: @Tyler Also, you cannot try to hide a script from Javascript, because Javascript runs on the browser. That means the only way it will be able to access a script is if the user can just as easily browser to it directly. That is how Javascript works.

Comment: @Felix, It _is_ going through a web server.

Comment: @TylerCrompton: Can you call the URL manually and pass parameters? Does it work then? You have to figure out whether it is a problem of the PHP script or the JavaScript script.

Comment: @Tyler: Mike is right. Try making an GET request from browser's address bar: `[substitute with your domain]/home2/crompton/scripts/calendar.php?month=3&year=11`, do you get `<div>GET</div>` in response, or a 404?

Comment: @Majid, Wouldn't having the `'/'` as the first character tell the server that it is an absolute path starting at the root directory?

Comment: @Tyler, `/path` makes the call to be put to `http://domain/path` even if the page is on `http://domain/some/other/path`

Comment: @TylerCrompton: So? Does calling the URL manually in the browser and passing parameters work?

Comment: @Felix, Hmm. That comment on w3schools was vague about paths. However, it still works. The page updates but it returns the current month's calendar because of my if statements at the bottom of the PHP file. I'm pretty sure it's calling the server. It might not but my browser says it is doing something each time the link is clicked.

Comment: @Felix, You can't access calendar.php directly. Only the server can access it. Relative to the `public_html` folder, it is in `../scripts`.

Comment: @TylerCrompton: If only the server can access it then the Ajax request won't work, as it is sent from the client. Sending an Ajax request is like typing the URL in the browser, just a bit different ;) That is why I said you cannot "protect" this URL. Make sure you script is accessible via the browser and then try again with the Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

@Mike: true, GET requests do not work to OS paths, only to server paths.

Anyway, you should always use absolute paths in situations like these, it's safer:

`xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/home2/crompton/scripts/calendar.php?month=" + month + "&year=" + year, true);`